# Canvas not drawing to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I've been looking around for an answer to this, re-written my code multiple times, still nothing. Essentially I am trying to draw to a JFrame containing just a simple rectangle, yet each time nothing shows in the Frame - its just blank.

```
package com.Graphics;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphicsMain myGraphics = new GraphicsMain();

        myGraphics.createDisplay();

    }

    void createDisplay(){

        int width = 500;
        int height = 500;
        String title = "TestFrame";
        Graphics g;

        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame(title);

        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setResizable(false);
        myFrame.setSize(width, height);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myCanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        myCanvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        myCanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        myFrame.add(myCanvas);
        myFrame.pack();

        myCanvas.createBufferStrategy(2);

        BufferStrategy bs = myCanvas.getBufferStrategy();

        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(10, 50, 50, 70);

        bs.show();
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

I realize conventions here are terrible - this is just a practice for me with graphics. Normally I would have this broken into separate classes etc. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen Please don't suggest edits [such as you did here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20122408) which simply remove all blank lines from code. This actively hurts readability, and in this case there was an actual problem with the code formatting (the indentation) which you didn't bother to fix. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code.

Comment: You should use `JPanel`, and override the `paintComponent(Graphics gc)` method, and draw your rectangle in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferStrategy` is a low level painting mechanism which places full control of the painting process in your hands.  With this "power" comes some complexity which you need to be ready to manage

The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) provide a number of excellent examples into how you must manage the API.

The API is volatile, this means that you need to make a number of checks to ensure that what you've been painting has been passed to the rendering pipeline/hardware correctly, otherwise you need to repeat the paint pass again.  This is where you're probably having issues.

You also need to remember that, while `setVisible` returns immediately, this doesn't mean that the window is visible on the screen or that it's been fully realised (attached to a native peer), this can also affect when `BufferStrategy` is ready to paint.

For example...

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int WIDTH = 200;
    public static int HEIGHT = 200;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Test() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();

    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            update();
            render();

            // Control frame rate
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

    }

    public void update() {
        // Make changes to the model which need to be painted
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        do {
            do {
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
                // You MUST clear the page before painting, bad things
                // happen otherwise
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(10, 50, 50, 70);
                g.dispose();
            } while (bs.contentsRestored());
            bs.show();
        } while (bs.contentsLost());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(test);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        test.start();

    }

}
```

Now, this example also has a basic concept of a "main loop", this is responsible for providing base line from which you can generate dynamic content and render it.  But you could simply try calling `render` one the window is made visible

As I said, `BufferStrategy` is a low level API, it's powerful, flexible and complex to manage.

A simpler solution might be to go a custom painting route through Swing. See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.  Swing components offer automatic double buffering and the paint scheduling is done for you (although you do need to use things like `repaint` to get a paint pass to run)

Comment: Thanks for the help MadProgrammer. I think i've got some studying to do on this API... haha xD

Comment: just a quick question regarding _why_ one must do it the way you did above? I essentially did all of that in the method I posted above, but obviously excluding the Thread & various methods. Just confused on why one must do it that way. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: @Matthew What you didn't do, was check to see if the contents of the buffer was successfully passed to the rendering pipeline (ie if the buffer was invalidated during the painting process) - see the double `do-while` loop in the `render` method.  As I said, just because you called `setVisible` doesn't mean the window is visible (on the screen) or that it's ready for painting

Comment: Ah ok, you said that at the start of your message as well. Missed it somehow. Final question on this then, why does such a thing happen? Why would the contents of the buffer not successfully pass?

Comment: @Matthew The memory of a video card is shared and "volatile", this means that the video card can decide to take it away from you (or do other things), because the `BufferStrategy` is trying to operate at the lowest possible level it can, it doesn't guard against this, it just lets you know when it happens

Comment: One more question - reviewing the code further, I noticed that while you created a stop() method, you never actually called the method anywhere in the code (or at least it appeared you didn't?). I added it in @the end of my main. When I ran the program, everything seemed to run normally - only difference was that when I minimized the frame, the rectangle that was drawn to it disappeared. Whats going on w/ that?

Comment: @Matthew Canvas uses a “active” paint algorithm, this provides you with full control over the painting process, but also means you need to perform a rendering pass in any situation which might cause damage to the view. When you call stop, nothing is making rendering passes, so when you minimise the window, it’s “graphics” is also “destroyed”, so when the window is restored, so does its graphics