# Will the data be kept when drawing on top of another drawing in java graphics?

Tags: java, graphics

Say for example I have this:

```
public static void drawString(){
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawString("TEXT, 5, 25);
}
```

If I were to run this method multiple times, the string "TEXT" will be drawn on top of each other. Does the string that was originally there before being overlapped by another string be kept or would it be erased?

Comment: Yes and no. Because you have "pages" onto which you draw, unless you draw on ALL the pages, it's possible that some might be missed (and not display anything). If the text has previous been drawn, then yes, you will simply be painting over it. As a general rule of thumb, you should clear the page before repainting the entire current state. Beware, calling getDrawGraphics will return what ever page the strategy is currently using as the offscreen context, it could be switched or invalidated so it's better to maintain your own reference to it and use it to paint the entire state in a single pass

Comment: @MadProgrammer as you mentioned, how would I paint the entire state in a single pass?

Comment: Something like [this the answer to this question demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032244/canvas-not-drawing-to-jframe)